# order by problem in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here total two union binding three queries, first query retrieving records from a virtual table(Inner query) and two simple queries retrieving records from a physical tables.
All three queries making a virtual table named "vertulatable" retrieving all records from "vertualtable" with group by and order by clause.
But the problem is its not doing a proper descending order by final price. Some records retrieved from mediater query has value 150 but showing after 0 or less then 150,but should be top from 0 or less then 150 in resultant records.

```
SELECT 
sum(vertualtable.WyoPrice) as WyoPrice, 
       sum(vertualtable.normalPrice) as normalPrice, 
       vertualtable.sbnam,
       vertualtable.sbwynum, 
      if(vertualtable.sbwynum in(25,43), 
           sum(vertualtable.WyoPrice), sum(vertualtable.normalPrice)) as finalPricePrev,
        sum(vertualtable.finalPrice) as  finalPrice,
     vertualtable.BuilderStatus

 FROM (


SELECT sum(vertualtbl.WyoPrice) as WyoPrice, 
       sum(vertualtbl.normalPrice) as normalPrice, 
       vertualtbl.sbnam,
       vertualtbl.sbwynum, 
      if(vertualtbl.sbwynum in(25,43), 
           sum(vertualtbl.WyoPrice), sum(vertualtbl.normalPrice)) as finalPrice,
     'Main' as BuilderStatus
FROM(

  select 
        b.sbnam,
        b.sbwynum,
        'g'        as g,
        sum(if (s.adjprice > 0, s.adjprice, if (s.price > 0, s.price,
         s.estprice))) as normalPrice,
        st.forsearchwoy,
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',
               F_offshorePrice(s.topsbwynum, s.hulsbwynum, s.sbwynum, s.adjprice,
            s.price, s.estprice, s.pricehulint, s.pricetopint, s.pricehulcons,
             s.pricetop, s.priceint, s.pricetht),0)) as WyoPrice
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.sbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum > 0) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')

 group by s.tblshipwynum



 ) vertualtbl group by vertualtbl.sbwynum 




UNION 

  select 
        '0' as WyoPrice,
        '0' as normalPrice,
        b.sbnam as sbnam,        
        s.hulsbwynum as sbwynum,
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',s.pricehulcons,0)) as finalPrice,
        'HUL' as BuilderStatus
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.hulsbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum != s.hulsbwynum and
       s.hulsbwynum > 0 ) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')
 group by s.hulsbwynum



  UNION

  select 
       '0' as WyoPrice,
       '0' as normalPrice,
        b.sbnam as sbnam,        
        s.topsbwynum as sbwynum,        
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',s.pricetop,0)) as finalPrice,
        'TOP' as BuilderStatus
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.topsbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum != s.topsbwynum and
       s.topsbwynum > 0 ) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')
  group by s.hulsbwynum 

 ) as vertualtable 

 group by vertualtable.sbnam
 order by vertualtable.finalPrice desc
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small modifications to your query - try to see if the result is the one you expected

```
SELECT 
sum(vertualtable.WyoPrice) as WyoPrice, 
       sum(vertualtable.normalPrice) as normalPrice, 
       vertualtable.sbnam AS sbnam,
       vertualtable.sbwynum, 
      if(vertualtable.sbwynum in(25,43), 
           sum(vertualtable.WyoPrice), sum(vertualtable.normalPrice)) as finalPricePrev,
        sum(vertualtable.finalPrice) as  finalPrice,
     vertualtable.BuilderStatus

 FROM (


SELECT sum(vertualtbl.WyoPrice) as WyoPrice, 
       sum(vertualtbl.normalPrice) as normalPrice, 
       vertualtbl.sbnam AS sbnam,
       vertualtbl.sbwynum, 
      if(vertualtbl.sbwynum in(25,43), 
           sum(vertualtbl.WyoPrice), sum(vertualtbl.normalPrice)) as finalPrice,
     'Main' as BuilderStatus
FROM(

  select 
        b.sbnam AS sbnam,
        b.sbwynum,
        'g'        as g,
        sum(if (s.adjprice > 0, s.adjprice, if (s.price > 0, s.price,
         s.estprice))) as normalPrice,
        st.forsearchwoy,
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',
               F_offshorePrice(s.topsbwynum, s.hulsbwynum, s.sbwynum, s.adjprice,
            s.price, s.estprice, s.pricehulint, s.pricetopint, s.pricehulcons,
             s.pricetop, s.priceint, s.pricetht),0)) as WyoPrice
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.sbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum > 0) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')

 group by s.tblshipwynum



 ) vertualtbl group by vertualtbl.sbwynum 




UNION 

  select 
        '0' as WyoPrice,
        '0' as normalPrice,
        b.sbnam as sbnam,        
        s.hulsbwynum as sbwynum,
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',s.pricehulcons,0)) as finalPrice,
        'HUL' as BuilderStatus
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.hulsbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum != s.hulsbwynum and
       s.hulsbwynum > 0 ) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')
 group by s.hulsbwynum



  UNION

  select 
       '0' as WyoPrice,
       '0' as normalPrice,
        b.sbnam as sbnam,        
        s.topsbwynum as sbwynum,        
        SUM(if (st.forsearchwoy = 'Y',s.pricetop,0)) as finalPrice,
        'TOP' as BuilderStatus
 from tblship s
      left join tblbuilder b on b.sbwynum = s.topsbwynum and b.deleted = 'N'
      left join tblshiptype as st on st.wytypid = s.wytypid
 where s.deleted != 'Y' and
      (s.sbwynum != s.topsbwynum and
       s.topsbwynum > 0 ) and
       status in ('O', 'FO', 'JV', 'PR', 'C', 'F')
  group by s.hulsbwynum 

 ) as vertualtable 

 group by sbnam
 order by finalPrice desc
```